# encode to arabic proplem

Tags: php, utf-8, encode

i need change encode to windows-1256 like this:

```
print utf8_encode($text)
```

not ture:

```
print windows-1256_encode($text)
```

Comment: Please explain more about where your data is coming from, and what format you want to output it in.

Comment: this output ����� .. after decode utf8 i see english text but in arabic i see this: ??????

Comment: @Anas where does your data come from, a database or the file itself? What encoding is your page in, UTF-8 or Windows-1256?

Comment: i use wordpress and i write text in page not from database

Comment: @Anas can you show a live link? You need to find out which encoding your blog uses. The browser's  "character set" menu should show you.

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same problem as you do where I wanted to retrieve Arabic data fields from SQL Server 2008 R2 with php using ODBC connection and then I found that getting the right information depends on using " iconv " like this:

```
echo iconv("","utf-8",$result);
```

So you can see I didn't mention the first encoding but the way I wanted to display my Arabic data (utf8).

Answer (score 0):

did you try the function  mb_convert_encoding

see:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php and 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Stewie's answer you can use the [iconv](http://php.net/iconv) functions.